# Example of usage of operator -> in iterators C++

Tags: c++, iterator

I do understand how the operator -> is used in classes, but I don't understand how its used in iterators. I think it is meant to be used to access member variables, but C++ Random Access Iterators do not have any public member variables. So how is it used? Could someone give me an example?

Comment: Lets say you have a `class_type *`, what does `class_type->` access?  The pointer or the thing the pointer points to?

Comment: `operator ->` is overloaded on iterators to give access to the value type's members.

Comment: If using iterators to go through a `std::vector<std::string>`, how would you find the length of each string? That's a trivial example, it would have been worth writing some more code before thinking this was a useless feature.

Comment: An iterator *is* a class.

Comment: "I think it is meant to be used to access member variables,  ..." - sometimes yes. "... but C++ Random Access Iterators do not have any public member variables" - they can have private members, moreover `operator->` does not necessarily access a member

Comment: @JesperJuhl not necessarily, `int *` is the iterator of `int[10]`

Comment: @Caleth True. I should have said "is *usually* a class".

Answer (score 0):

an expression involving `operator ->` of a class type is defined to recursively evaluate `->` on the result of the member operator until it reaches a pointer.

> A *class member access operator function* is a function named `operator->` that is a non-static member function taking no parameters. For an expression of the form
>
> *postfix-expression* `-> template`<sub>opt</sub> *id-expression*
>
> the operator function is selected by overload resolution ([over.match.oper]), and the expression is interpreted as
>
> `(` *postfix-expression* `. operator -> () ) -> template`<sub>opt</sub> *id-expression*

[[over.ref]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.ref)

If you iterator type is a class (which not all iterator types are), then it must have an `operator->`, which will (transitively) return a pointer to the object it points to. `std::vector<int>::iterator::operator->` will return an `int*`, `std::set<std::string>::iterator::operator->` will return a `const std::string *`, etc.